# python multiindex array datetime formatting (as two different datetimes)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, date-formatting, multi-index, python-datetime

I have the following data:

```
     level_0   level_1   level_2
0    90936.0   91908.0  Profile1  
1    92551.0   93049.0      Run1
2    93459.0   94053.0  Profile2
3    94723.0   95333.0  Profile3
4    95444.0   95713.0      Run2
5   100221.0  100758.0      Run3
6   100937.0  101243.0      Run4
```

I would like to format the columns `level_0` and `level_1` as the times at which the observations were initiated (`level_0`) and ended(`level_1`):

```
     level_0   level_1   level_2
0    9:09:36   9:19:08  Profile1  
1    9:25:51   9:30:49      Run1
2    9:34:59   9:40:53  Profile2
3    9:47:23   9:53:33  Profile3
4    9:54:44   9:57:13      Run2
5   10:02:21  10:07:58      Run3
```

How can I do that ? 
Thanks

Comment: Is this in `pandas`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your dataframe is in `pandas`. In this case, one way is to use `apply` to apply `pd.to_datetime` to both columns, then use `dt.time` to access just the time string:

```
df[['level_0','level_1']] = df[['level_0','level_1']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%H%M%S.0').dt.time)
>>> df
    level_0   level_1   level_2
0  09:09:36  09:19:08  Profile1
1  09:25:51  09:30:49      Run1
2  09:34:59  09:40:53  Profile2
3  09:47:23  09:53:33  Profile3
4  09:54:44  09:57:13      Run2
5  10:02:21  10:07:58      Run3
6  10:09:37  10:12:43      Run4
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works. One more question - I m trying now to transform the date into seconds ( since 00:00:00) by doing s_df = df_event['level_0'].dt.total_seconds(). The error messages is "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values". Is this not a datime value ? ( I used to_datetime to get this right so it should be a datetime value ? )

Comment: No, I think you'll have to use `to_timedelta`. For example: `pd.to_timedelta(df['level_0'].astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()`